# Django - Datetime field shown as in admin panel

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms

I have a model where I can create objects without a problem from the admin panel, I created a form to do the same directly within the website but I cannot manage to create an object directly from the form because of the error shown in the second picture. It is the "DateTimeField". Best case scenario, someone knows which piece of code is required for the form to display a menu ( as shown in picture 1 ) where the user can click which time and date he wants to.

Thank you very much

[image: Django]

Second image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`bootstrap-datepicker` might be a good bet : https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. But you will need to manually handle its JS behaviour. Not that simple.

Alternative with some guidance here : https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/03/how-to-use-date-picker-with-django.html